Working with files in C in Ubuntu (WSL), program crashing
I have a problem I cant solve for the past 2 weeks. In my school we have a course where we are learning about opoerating systems and we are forced to work within WSL environment, in Ubuntu.
One of the tasks is to create a simple program that reads from and writes to files and then is used to receive signals (SIGINT, SIGTERM etc.), but the trouble I am having is that the program crashes immediately when I run it.
It worked well when I simply compiled and ran it inside Windows environment but now when I want to use file locations inside Ubuntu home directory (so that I can access those via Ubuntu terminal) it doesnt work, it crashes immediately upon starting.
int main()
{
    //main part of program

    int broj;
    FILE *fptr1;
    FILE *fptr2;

    fptr1=fopen("\\wsl.localhost\\Ubuntu\\home\\asevic\\lab1\\obrada.txt", "r+");
    fptr2=fopen("\\wsl.localhost\\Ubuntu\\home\\asevic\\lab1\\status.txt", "r+");

    int n =0;

    if(fptr1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(fptr2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(2);
    }
    while(fscanf( fptr2, "%d", &n ) == 1);

    fclose(fptr2);
    printf("Program s PID=%ld krenuo s radom\n", (long) getpid());
    printf( "The last number in the file is: %d\n", n );

    fptr2=fopen("\\wsl.localhost\\Ubuntu\\home\\asevic\\lab1\\status.txt", "r+");

    int kv, counter=n+1;
    int i;
    for(i=n+1;i<1000;++i)
    {
        kv=i*i;
        fprintf(fptr1,"%d\n",kv);
        fprintf(fptr2,"%d\n",counter);
        printf("Next square value: %d\n", kv);
        counter++;
        sleep(3);
    }
    printf("Program ends\n");
    
    return 0;
}

this is the code I am using, I believe the issue is in the file paths. But those are the paths to the Ubuntu home directory where the c file, and the to be created txt files are located.
Can anyone shed some light on the issue?
Regards,
Adrian
Like I said, the program works within the Windows environment but fails when Ubuntu home directory file paths are included. I also get an "Error!" message when trying to run from Ubuntu terminal, signalling tghat files are not being created.

Linux doesn't use backslashes for pathnames, it uses forward slashes.

Windows also understands forward slashes, so you can use them all the time and the code will be portable.

In the future, please use perror or errno to get the specific error code when a function like fopen fails, so you can better understand what went wrong (e.g. file not found, permission error, etc).  Also, include in your question the full output of your program, along with any input that you gave to it.

If you run the program inside WSL, then the path should probably be
"/home/asevic/lab1/obrada.txt"

@eltomito One of the answers already says that.

@Barmar If that doesn't work then I'm sorry, I've never used WSL, just plain Linux.

@eltomito I didn't say it doesn't work, just that someone already posted that and there's no point in posting it as a comment.

"It worked well when I simply compiled and ran it inside Windows environment" Did you use the same file pathes or some other folders?

Where does your program crash? If files cannot be created due to incorrect path names, you will detect NULL and the Error! messages comes from your own program before you call exit. That is not a crash. It is just error handling.


Network paths (UNC paths) start with \\ (two backslashes). So you need to escape them twice:

"\\\\wsl.localhost\\Ubuntu\\home\\asevic\\lab1\\status.txt"


If you run program under WSL or native Linux use slashes / and different paths

"/home/asevic/lab1/status.txt"


Check Windows WSL path using wslpath -w /home/asevic/lab1/status.txt command.


Why did it work when they ran it from the Windows environment?

@Barmar I doubt if it did

Those are the Windows file paths, but you're running the program in WSL. Your paths need to be relative to the / route. Also, UNIX paths use forward slashes, not backslashes.
The correct route would be ~/lab1/obrada.txt where the tilde is the /home/USER directory

You can't use ~ from C, that's expanded by the shell.

Well, you can if you use wordexp(3) or something to expand it.

Oh shit I thought that was the OS. Wild.

I tried changing the path names but to no avail.
